# react-google-autocomplete returns me a different language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-autocomplete

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm using a react-google-autocomplete and as you can see, autocomplete results are not english(US).

Here's my codes

```
<StyledAutoComplete
                apiKey={process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}
                onPlaceSelected={(place) =>...}
                options={{
                    types: ['administrative_area_level_1'],
                    componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' },
                }}
                language={'en'}
            />
```

I set language as an English but result isn't what I intended.
Is there any information ??